# How to set space between radio button to text in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**My Custom renderer for Radio Button is,**

public class RadioButtonRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomRadioButton> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);


        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            e.OldElement.PropertyChanged += ElementOnPropertyChanged;                                
        }

        if (this.Control == null)
        {
            var radButton = new RadioButton(this.Context);
            radButton.CheckedChange += radButton_CheckedChange;

            this.SetNativeControl(radButton);
        }

        Control.Text = e.NewElement.Text;
        Control.Checked = e.NewElement.Checked;

        Element.PropertyChanged += ElementOnPropertyChanged;
    }
```

Can anybody know how to set space between radio button to text.

Comment: Add screen shot how look like now and how you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android `RadioButton` widget is a `CompoundButton` and you can set its `TextView`'s relative padding:

[image]

```
Control.SetPaddingRelative(150, 0, 0, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Its working fine :) @SushiHangover